# Need to increment column value based on Other column In SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a scenario like below.

Source Data like below (XML File)::

```
ID        CatType           Name
11           A              Raj
22           A              Rai
33           B              Raki
44           B              Krish
55           A              Rem
66           B              Ram
```

I have to load above into below formate.

```
ID       CatType        Name       LegacyID
1              A        Raj           11
2              A        Rai           22
1              B        Raki          33
2              B        Krish         44
3              A        Rem           55
3              B        Ram           66
```

`ID` and `CatType` are composite key in my destination table. I am getting CatType from source. While loading data, I have to increment ID by selecting Max(ID) where CatType= ?(based on CatType) in Destination table
How can I load these records in SSIS, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes i have thought we can achieve by using SQL Task in control flow. But not sure.

Comment: @Siva I just updated my question with source data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample SSIS package created using `SSIS 2008 R2` that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve. The sample package loads the incoming file data into a staging table. Then using the SQL Server `Rank` function in conjunction with `Partition` clause you can load the data as per your requirement. This sample assumes that your database version `SQL Server 2005 or above`. Since you didn't provide an exact XML file format, I have used CSV file format as the input files.

- Let's create two sample CSV files named `Source_001.csv` and `Source_002.csv`. Two files were created just to show the package logic works.

[image: Source_001]

[image: Source_002]

- In the SQL Server database, create the destination table named `dbo.CategoryName`. This is the final table where data will be loaded into. It has the composite key on the columns `Id` and `CatType`.

[image: Destination table]

- In the SQL Server database, create the staging table named `dbo.CategoryName_Staging`. This is where the file data will be loaded into temporarily. This staging table structure mimics the incoming file structure.

[image: Staging table]

- In the SQL Server database, create a stored procedure named **`dbo.PopulateDestination`** using the script provided in the section *Stored Procedure Script* provided in the bottom of this post. This stored procedure uses **`RANK`** function in combination with **`PARTITION`** clause to identify the correct Id that should be assigned to the CatType values.
- Create a new SSIS package. Create an OLE DB Connection manager named `SQLServer`. This will point to your SQL Server database. Created a Flat File connection manager named `Source`.

[image: Connection managers]

- Configure the flat file connection manager as shown below. I had placed the source csv file in the path `C:\temp\`

[image: Flat File General]

- On the *Advanced* tab of the *Flat File Connection Manager Editor*, rename the column information. `LegacyId` - **integer**, `CatType` - **string (10)**, `Name` - **string (30)** the numbers denote the OutputColumnWidth.

[image: flat file columns]

- On the SSIS package's control flow tab, place an `Execute SQL task`, followed by `Data Flow Task` and then followed by another `Execute SQL task`.

[image: SSIS control flow]

- Double-click on the first Execute SQL task and configure it to truncate the staging table.

[image: Truncate staging table]

- Double-click on the Data Flow Task to switch to the data flow tab. Inside the data flow tab, place a Flat File Source manager to read the CSV file and place an OLE DB Destination to write the data into the staging table.

[image: Data flow task]

- Configure the flat file source as shown below to read the flat file source using the flat file connection manager.

[image: Flat file connection manager]

[image: Flat file columns]

- Configure the OLE DB destinaton as shown below to accept the incoming data and write into the destination file.

[image: OLE DB connection manager]

[image: OLE DB columns]

- Go back to Control flow tab, configure the last Execute SQL task to invoke the newly created stored procedure. The package development is now complete.

[image: Execute SQL task to run stored procedure]

- Execute the package. Remember, the package is configured to read only the first source file **Source_001.csv**. After the package execution, query the destination table **`CategoryName`** to find the following data.

[image: Destination after first execution]

- Now, stop the SSIS package execution, double-click on the Flat File Connection Manager named **`Source`**. Change the file name path to **`Source_002.csv`** in order to read the second file.

[image: Change flat file connection file name]

- Execute the package again. The package is now configured to read the second source file **Source_002.csv**. This execution will append rows to the already populated desitnation table. After the package execution, query the destination table **`CategoryName`** to find the following addition data and note that the Id columns is correctly populater.

Hope that helps.

[image: Destination table after second execution]

**`Stored Procedure Script`**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PopulateDestination]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.CategoryName (Id, CatType, Name, LegacyId)
    SELECT      MAXID.Id + RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CatType ORDER BY LegacyId) Id
            ,   CS.CatType
            ,   CS.Name
            ,   CS.LegacyId
    FROM        dbo.CategoryName_Staging    CS
    CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT  COALESCE(MAX(Id), 0) Id
                    FROM    dbo.CategoryName C
                    WHERE   C.CatType = CS.CatType
                ) MAXID
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much Siva For this step by step explanation. Thanks alot its working good. :)

Answer (score 1):

so what you really need is to create a new ID column based on cat type and change the column name from ID to legacy ID?

If yes, you can do both things using a [derived column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)